# Need help about giving relationships in database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-theory, rdbms

I am developing a simple blog application in which users can write posts and others can like, comment, share etc. i am facing difficulty in designing database.
What I have tried is:

```
user (user_id(pk), user_name)

post (post_id(pk), post_content, likes, user_id(fk))

comment(comment_id(pk), comment, post_id(fk))
```

**PROBLEM:** One user can have many posts and many users can like and comment on many posts. Whether I have to separate two tables like: `user`, `post` and `userpost`?

Can anyone tell me if anything wrong in this design?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this

```
user (user_id(pk), user_name)

post (post_id(pk),user_id(fk), post_content)

comment(comment_id(pk),post_id(fk),user_id(fk), comment)

likes(post_id(fk), user_id(fk) status)
```

In `status` column in `likes` table you can save it as `like` or `unlike` can be tinyint field with

```
NULL - Default value
True - Like and False - unlike(if you have unlike option)
```

Comment: thnx..I want is to count how many likes the post have from other users, and to know which users have liked the post (same as facebook)

Comment: You can query like `Select count(*) from like where post_id= @postId` and similarly for user_id

Comment: I mean, Will I necessarily have to make another table for likes?

Comment: yes, that will be better as Many user can like Many post. M-M relation so it need to have a table to save like info

Comment: Yes I think you will

Comment: @JamesAnderson ,@vijayp...thnks. i'll accept it.

Comment: upvoted! what is the primary key in comment

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is add `user_id` to your `comment` table. That way each comment can be linked to a post and a user.

Comment: The @vijayp answer is worth a look as I think the extra tables for likes is a good idea but the table should be called likes and not the reserved word like

Comment: But, all I want is to count how many likes the post have from other users, and to know which users have liked the post (same as facebook)